# Convert back localized NSString number (> 4 digits) to integer

Tags: objective-c, ios6, type-conversion

I used the `localizedStringWithFormat:` method on `NSString` class to convert a seven digit integer number to an NSString somewhere in my code and need to *convert it back to an integer now.*

As my App is localized for different regions with different separators after three digits (e.g. '.' in the U.S. and ',' in Germany), **what's the best way to convert a localized NSString integer value to an integer?**

I tried `integerValue` on my string as follows but it didn't work:

```
// Somewhere in code:
int num = 1049000;
NSString *myLocalizedNumString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
// myLocalizedNumString (U.S.): '1,049,000'
// myLocalizedNumString (Germany): '1.049.000'

// Somewhere else where I have a reference to my string but none to the num:
int restoredNum = [myLocalizedNumString integerValue];
// restoredNum isn't 1049000 (it's 0, the initial value)
```

What would be a good working way of doing it?

Comment: So you have somehow lost the reference to the original number?

Comment: That's right. I wouldn't ask if I didn't ;)

Comment: Yet this is a runtime problem. So why can't you store the original number? And if you know the localisation of the formatting your can use a number formatter to get it back.

Comment: I can already fetch the number from a UI element that stores an  `NSString` value thus I don't want to store it twice.

Comment: That's the wrong way to look at it. The number you hold would effectively be your model data, and the string would be your view representation. You aren't holding it twice, you just have 2 different things. The fact that you can get a string from a UI component doesn't make it suitable storage.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on how to design my app. I'm sure you would be a good teacher on software engineering. But sometimes people just need a fast solution for a bad engineered software. Sorry for my missing engineering qualities ... o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its name `NSNumberFormatter` converts both ways, it is also a string parser. Using the method `numberFromString` after setting the number formatter’s `numberStyle` property to `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` solves your problem.

The code might look as follows:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle; 
NSInteger restoredNum = [[formatter numberFromString:myLocalizedNumString] integerValue];
```

Comment: I tried this as follows but it didn't work either: `NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                            [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
                            [formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
                            NSString *valueString = @"1,049,000";
                            int value = [[formatter numberFromString:valueString] integerValue];`

Comment: You need to specify the style as well, try adding `formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;`

Comment: Thanks, `numberStyle` was even the ONLY property I needed to set to make all work. My working code looks as follows: `NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                            formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
                            int restoredNum = [[formatter numberFromString:myLocalizedNumString] integerValue];`

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you update it with working example code (similar to mine above). So others can immediately see the full code solution.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Did not looking up the class and working out the solution aid your *understanding*? Are you not better of because of that than simply copying a pre-canned solution?

Comment: I'm not saying this because I want others to be able to copy and paste but because I think it's not part of the *understanding* to find out that the `numberStyle` property is the one to go. A solution should in my opinion at least also direct to that property.

Comment: Let's differ. Understanding `NSNumberFormatter` is understanding the properties required to configure it - someone else may misunderstand a different property. Have a nice day.

Comment: One doesn't have to know every single street to find his way to his destination. If someone asks you how to get somewhere, do you tell him all the streets nearby the shortest/easiest/best road as well? I don't. And I also don't want to know them when I ask someone else for directions.